# Issues using redux saga

Tags: reactjs

I added to my application redux saga, but i don't know why, but it does not work.
I have the next code:
My saga

```js
export function* sagaWatcher () {
    yield takeEvery(FETCH_DATA, sagaWorker)
}

function* sagaWorker() {
    const payload  = yield call(fetchData());
    yield put({type:FETCH_DATA, payload})
}
 const fetchData = () => {
        fetch(api',{
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'method': 'GET',
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => result)
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
}
```

Data from Reducer:

```js
case FETCH_DATA: {
 console.log(action.payload)
    return {
       ...state,
      data: action.payload
  }
}
```

Data from store:

```js
const saga = createSagaMiddleware();

export const store = createStore(reducer,     compose(
    applyMiddleware(saga),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
))

saga.run(sagaWatcher)
```

This is my all code related to this `get` request.

With this code i don't get  anything in `data` varaible. Which is the problem in my saga? How to solve it?

Comment: Assuming you dispatch `FETCH_DATA` somewhere in your app and aware of an infitite loop because redispatching of `FETCH_DATA` in saga. You don't need to call a function when you pass it in `call`. So instead of `const payload  = yield call(fetchData());` you need to write `const payload  = yield call(fetchData);`

Comment: @Shlang ,,[Assuming you dispatch FETCH_DATA ]...what do you mean? how should i dispatch it?

Comment: In the [same way](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) as any other action

Comment: @Shlang, could you take a look to my code and to show me how it should be:  https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-rosalind-lp16j?file=/src/App.js:242-328

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-mccarthy-werhj?file=/src/App.js) is fixed sandbox. It may be better to learn the basics of react and redux before getting redux-saga.

Comment: @Shlang, when i do   `console.log(selector.data)` i get an emty object.

Comment: @Shlang, do you have the same issue or is just on my side ?